# GenericTabularInline isn't returning what it should in my Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, generic-foreign-key

I have the following `models.py` file:

```
class Product(Model):
    ...

class ExtraService(Model):
    ...

class Order(Model):
    ...

class OrderItem(Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(verbose_name=_('Order Item'), to=Order)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    item_relation = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name=_('Quantity'), default=0)
```

And I'm working my `admin.py` this way:

```
class OrderItemInlineAdmin(GenericTabularInline):
    model = OrderItem
    min_num = 0
    extra = 0
    fields = ('item_relation', 'quantity',)
    ct_field = 'content_type'
    ct_fk_field = 'object_id'

class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user_form',)
    inlines = (OrderItemInlineAdmin,)

admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
```

I can't get my admin to show the OrderItem object inline (which can have a key to either a Product or an ExtraService) with my Order object, followed by its quantity field. Instead, it says the `item_relation` field is unknown:

```
FieldError at /admin/product/order/13/
Unknown field(s) (item_relation) specified for OrderItem
```

How do I bypass this?

PS: I've also tried using my own ModelForm but it still doesn't recognize the `item_relation` field.

PS1: If I don't define a fields variable in `OrderItemInlineAdmin`, I end up with something like this, which is incorrect because I have existing OrderItem objects and this assumes I don't (no object selected and no quantity?): [image: not what I need]